# The mobile number gets verified without code second time using account kit

Tags: android, account-kit

I am trying to implement the mobile verification using account kit. The number is gets verified with the code at the first time but its gets verified itself with out code second time. I have implemented as follows:

```
 public void phoneLogin() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountKitActivity.class);
    uiManager = new SkinManager(SkinManager.Skin.TRANSLUCENT,
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.cancel_ride_color), R.drawable.banner, SkinManager.Tint.WHITE, 85);
    configurationBuilder =
            new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                    LoginType.PHONE,
                    AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN); // or .ResponseType.TOKEN
    configurationBuilder.setUIManager(uiManager);
    intent.putExtra(
            AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
            configurationBuilder.build());
    startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

On Activity Result, I have implemented as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        final int requestCode,
        final int resultCode,
        final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null) {
        if (requestCode == APP_REQUEST_CODE) { // confirm that this response matches your request
            AccountKitLoginResult loginResult = data.getParcelableExtra(AccountKitLoginResult.RESULT_KEY);

            AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Account account) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: Account Kit" + account.getId());
                    Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: Account Kit" + AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
                    if (AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken() != null) {
                        SharedHelper.putKey(RegisterActivity.this, "account_kit_token", AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());

                        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = account.getPhoneNumber();
                        String phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.toString();
                        SharedHelper.putKey(RegisterActivity.this, "mobile", phoneNumberString);
                        registerAPI();
                    } else {
                        SharedHelper.putKey(RegisterActivity.this, "account_kit_token", "");
                        SharedHelper.putKey(RegisterActivity.this, "loggedIn", getString(R.string.False));
                        SharedHelper.putKey(context, "email", "");
                        SharedHelper.putKey(context, "login_by", "");
                        SharedHelper.putKey(RegisterActivity.this, "account_kit_token", "");
                        Intent goToLogin = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, WelcomeScreenActivity.class);
                        goToLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(goToLogin);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError: Account Kit" + accountKitError);
                    displayMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.social_cancel));
                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```